# Proof involving improper integral

Tags: calculus

> **Problem**: [image]

The solution say

> [image]

Can someone explain to me what the $h(N)$ and $g(N)$ are doing? Like, why is it there? The problem was $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{-N}^{N}f = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f$$, why do we need to change the $N$s to a general function?

Comment: It seems that they have purposely proved a more general case, for illustrating the solution to several such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h(N)$ and $g(N)$ are just functions of $N$ that tend to $\infty$ and $-\infty$ (respectively) as $N$ tends to $\infty$. The reason they appear in the proof is because Spivak is trying to show a more general statement to demonstrate the problem. To prove only the question that was originally asked you can take $h(N)=N$ and $g(N)=-N$.

Comment: Okay this makes me feel better about my proof.

Comment: Glad it makes you feel better. The proof should follow a similar technique as shown in the general version.